# how to remove the particular type of info from console NLog, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I use .net 5 console application and I would like to remove this type of information(see screen) from the console logging, but I want to log in console Info, Warnings, Errors, Debug levels.
How can I do it correctly using C# or nlog.config (XML)?

[image]

Comment: How are you using nlog?

Comment: Looks like output from NLog InternalLogger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging . You can either change `internalLogLevel="Warn"` or disable output to console `internalLogToConsole="false"` (Is disabled by default).

Comment: @RolfKristensen yep! thanks a lot it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like output from NLog InternalLogger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging.

You can either change `internalLogLevel="Warn"` or disable output to console `internalLogToConsole="false"` (Is disabled by default).